# Two .CSS style in one page?

Tags: css

So I'm currently trying to combine 2 separate .css files for my landing page. They both import different google fonts, problem is, as you all know the last .css style will override the first. Is there a good way to handle this issue or is it something that is not normally done? All class names are different as well.

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:600,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

maybe Im just not calling for the .css in the correct way...If you need more info from me, let me know. Is this a common issue?

Comment: what's your problem exactly ? do you meet any conflict in using those fonts ?

Comment: How do you expect us to do anything, you choose the design of your website, I don't understand why you need us to tell you which css rule to keep

Comment: I think it won't give any issue. Because both are different fonts and you are going refer with different names. No issues.

Comment: You can actually combine them into one line using the pipe delimiter (like `<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700|Raleway:600,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`)

Comment: It is *not* true that “the last .css style will override the first”, so what is the problem. (If CSS declarations conflict, then the last one wins *other things being equal*, but you have not shown any CSS declarations.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this shouldn't be any problem at all. the Google fonts will be loaded separately. And you will call them into your css by writing the following code

```
h1, h2, h3 {
    font-family: 'Raleway';
}

p {
    font-family: 'Lato';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Google fonts allows you to add all fonts into a collection, because you are doing it separately, it is getting overwritten.

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,300italic|Raleway:600,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take advantage of Font Pairings.

In that case, you put a pipe character (vertical line) between each font type.

The code would appear as follows:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:600,900|Lato:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

[You can read more here](https://www.servage.net/blog/2013/06/21/using-google-fonts-and-styles-on-your-site/)